# How to Trim special Character \r in php

Tags: php

Can anybody tell me here how to trim the special character `\r\n` or \n in php? I know there is already trim function in php but that is not working.

While copying the email address from some other place and copying it into the excel field and during uploading i am getting the invalid email address error. But the email id is correct just due to the special character `\r` the error is showing. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Without code how can we help?

Comment: `trim()` trims the `\r` just fine. See: http://codepad.org/ST54oRYC

Comment: @SumitBijvani i cant copy the whole code of importing excel here as it is bit long program.and i am using a email validation code that is also working fine.i just want to know how to trim \r so that email validation doesnot fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From PHP docs for [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

> This function returns a string with whitespace stripped from the
>   beginning and end of str. Without the second parameter, trim() will
>   strip these characters:
>
> " " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
>   "\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
>   "\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
>   "\r" (ASCII 13
>   (0x0D)), a carriage return.
>   "\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
>   "\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.

See example here: http://codepad.org/O9xa42cw

Comment: i have tried trim but its not working.trim will only trim the value specifed in second argument to its function call.
if not speified it will trim extra space

Comment: Read the docs. If the second argument is not specified, it will trim all the characters I listed above. Also see my example.

Comment: the following worked for me           $email = preg_replace('~[[:cntrl:]]~', '', $email);
                  $email = preg_replace('~[.[:cntrl:]]~', '', $email);
                  $email = preg_replace('~[.[:cntrl:][:space:]]~', '', $email);

Comment: Glad that worked for you but a regular expression based search/replace will be significantly slower than trim().

Comment: If removing control characters from the string makes the regex work, you didn't have \r or \n in that string in the first place. So trim did work for the characters it should remove, but you had characters in there that trim does not remove unless told to.

Comment: @RishabhRaj: In case you weren't aware, `trim` only removes characters from the beginning and end of the string. If `\r` was somewhere in the middle of the string, trim won't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you make use of a simple `str_replace()` if `trim()` really doesn't work (It works actually) ?

```
<?php
$email = 'john@gmail.com\r';
echo str_replace('\r','',$email);
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$email = str_replace('\r', '', $email);
```

btw "\r" is called carriage return char (you know old typewriters?)

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "\nemail@email.com\n\r"; 
$string = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $string);
```